# How can I test Amazon Alexa apps with multiple users?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've been developing an Alexa skill and I need to keep some state between requests on a per-user basis. I'm using the flask-ask framework and it works well with a single user, but clearly I need to test with multiple users, preferably in a simulated environment at first so I can hammer it with multiple requests for multiple users. I don't consider the app ready to go to beta testing yet.

I've scoured the web for this but I can't seem to find an answer; short of setting up multiple Amazon accounts, is there an easy way to test a development skill for multiple users in a simulated environment?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we doesnt have feature to test with multiple user in simulated environment in development environment. In addition, the simulator is not supported for use in multiple browser tabs at the same time. Rather you can use simulator, voice using an Alexa-enabled device linked to developer account, ASK CLI or Use the skill testing features of the Skill Management API simultaneously to test as multiple users. for more details please refer [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#ways-to-test-an-alexa-skill) .

Hope this Helps you